# Hibernate inheritance JOINED + TABLE PER CLASS

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this strange hierarchy:

- Class `A` is abstract (but it is an entity)
- Class `B` (abstract) and C both extend class `A` (TABLE_PER_CLASS).
- Class `B` is also extended by classes `D` and `E` but this time it is JOINED.

I want the `ID` of the `A` class to be the `ID` of all others.

Can this be done?

I get strange errors of IDs. can any one show me how to map?

This is how I did it:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class A {
      @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    protected Integer id;
}
```

Class C:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "managers")
public class C extends A {
```

Class B:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bb")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class B extends A {
```

Class C,D:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cc"/"dd")
@DiscriminatorValue("CC"/"DD")
public class C (or D) extends B {
```

Comment: Have you looked at [Mixing Joined and Table per concrete class inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977717/mixing-joined-and-table-per-concrete-class-inheritance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While mixing inheritance strategies in an inheritance tree *can* be sort of accomplished (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3916998/131929 refers to [Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/)
-> 5.1.5 Mixing inheritance strategies (p207-p210)) I, and everybody else I know, advise against it.

Sidenote, I suggest you always use `@MappedSuperclass` rather than `@Entity` for abstract classes.